# spark build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.11.0)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-ide

I'm observing some build errors in Scala IDE. While I know how to fix, I still don't understand how that works under the hood. I first elaborate on my case, and ask the question at the very bottom.

environment: mac

spark version 2.4.5: `brew info apache-spark` returns `apache-spark: stable 2.4.5, HEAD`
From the official page (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html) I'm seeing this: `Spark 2.4.5 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x).` So, my understanding, that I need to choose scala of version 2.12 in the scala IDE

[image]

This ends up with many build errors (to save place, posting here only some of them):

[image]

from the errors I get the idea to try scala `2.11`. It works and fixes the build errors, but I'm not satisfied as I still don't understand how that works. The jar files mentioned in the error messages are all taken from the spark 2.4.5 installation folder (/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/jars/)

So, my questions are:

1. why choosing scala 2.11 fixes build errors given that I'm using spark 2.4.5 (which is built with 2.12 based on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html). Why scala 2.12 doesn't work
2. my understanding that most of the .jar files in the `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/jars` are built with scala 2.11. Just based on the file names: 
   breeze_2.11-0.13.2.jar, spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar, and many others. Is it expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll reply myself.

the statement "For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.5 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x)." (taken from here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html) is misleading.

[image]

here is the history of the spark releases:

2.4.1 (https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-1.html):

`In Apache Spark 2.4.1, Scala 2.12 support is GA, and it’s no longer experimental. We will drop Scala 2.11 support in Spark 3.0, so please provide us feedback.`
Thus spark is built with scala 2.12 starting from 2.4.1

2.4.2 (https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-1.html): `Note that Scala 2.11 support is deprecated from 2.4.1 onwards. As of 2.4.2, the pre-built convenience binaries are compiled for Scala 2.12.`

however at version 2.4.3, scala is reverted back to 2.11

2.4.3 (https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-3.html): `Note that 2.4.3 switched the default Scala version from Scala 2.12 to Scala 2.11, which is the default for all the previous 2.x releases except 2.4.2`